# in JS how can I write a function with two parameters (array, element) to .unshift an element to a NEW array?

Tags: arrays, function, parameters

I am asked to create a function, `addElementToBeginningOfArray`, with the parameters 'array' and 'element' which then returns a new array. I have got as far as writing:

```
function addElementToBeginningOfArray(array, element) {
    return `${array}.unshift${element}`
}
```

but this is not working for me. Would be grateful for assistance, thanks.

Comment: have u tried simply `array.unshift(element)` ?. Alternately u can also try `[element].concat(array)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is there any error message?

Comment: solved this problem, used the wrong operator - thanks for inputs though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a template literal, that is, a string, and you are not actually executing unshift on anything. Even if you did return the unshift, this would return the length of the array, not the actual array. You should write your code like this:

```js
function addElementToBeginningOfArray(array, element) {
    array.unshift(element)
    return array
}

console.log(addElementToBeginningOfArray(['el1','el2'], 'el3'))
```

Should you want to write this code more efficiently, you could shorten it with an arrow function and spread operator:

```js
const addElToStartOfArr = (arr, el) => [el, ...arr]

console.log(addElToStartOfArr(['el1','el2'], 'el3'))
```

All in all, I would recommend using unshift alone, rather than writing a function around it.